# What does `sym()` do regarding tidyeval?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rlang

```
library(tidyverse)
input_name <- "birth_year"
input_value <- 19

quo(filter(starwars, !!input_name == !!input_value))       # line 5
quo(filter(starwars, !!sym(input_name) == !!input_value))  # line 6
```

What's the difference between line #5 and line #6, and the use of the `sym()` function? Why is `sym()` only required on the left side of the equation in line #6?

Is the point of `sym()` to take character strings and unquote them into symbols?

#### Line 5

```
<quosure>
  expr: ^filter(data, "birth_year" == 19)
  env:  global
```

#### Line 6

```
<quosure>
  expr: ^filter(data, birth_year == 19)
  env:  global
```

Comment: A string is data in itself. A symbol is a reference, it points to, or represents, other data (often a column in a data frame in the dplyr case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the  first case, the column is not evaluated, it is the string that gets evaluated.  But, by converting to `symbol` and evaluate it, it returns the column values.  The `sym` is required in the `lhs` because we are not trying to get the literal value, but to extract the column value

According to `?sym`

> sym() creates a symbol from a string and syms() creates a list of symbols from a character vector.

and the `?"!!"`

> The !! operator unquotes its argument. It gets evaluated immediately in the surrounding context.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, the goal of `sym()` is to take character strings and parse them into symbols. The reason you need this on the left-hand side of the equality can be seen in `?filter`:

> ```
>  ...: Logical predicates defined in terms of the variables in
>       ‘.data’. Multiple conditions are combined with ‘&’. Only rows
>       where the condition evaluates to ‘TRUE’ are kept.
> ```

`filter( starwars, "birth_year" == 19 )` will always return no results, because the [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) `"birth_year"` is never equal to the integer literal `19` (which gets implicitly coerced to the character literal `"19"` in the comparison). By using `sym`, you are effectively parsing that string into a symbol, forcing `filter` to look at the column called `birth_year` in data frame `starwars`, rather than the literal string `"birth_year"`.

Conversely, you *don't* need `sym()` on the right-hand side of the equation, because there is no column `19` in `starwars`, and you're interested in the actual literal value `19` instead. If you were comparing two columns in the data frame, then you would want `sym()` on both sides of the equality. For example,

```
name1 <- "skin_color"
name2 <- "eye_color"
filter( starwars, !!sym(name1) == !!sym(name2) )
# # A tibble: 6 x 13
#   name  height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year gender homeworld
#   <chr>  <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
# 1 Wick…     88    20 brown      brown      brown              8 male   Endor    
# 2 Jar …    196    66 none       orange     orange            52 male   Naboo    
# 3 Eeth…    171    NA black      brown      brown             NA male   Iridonia 
# 4 Mas …    196    NA none       blue       blue              NA male   Champala 
# ...
```